# Allow a program to edit the current wallpaper

Tags: 12.04, wine, desktop-background, calendar

is there a way to allow a wine-based program to edit the actual Ubuntu wallpaper? I want to use a calender printing the dates on the wallpaper. It works for windows but I cannot set the changes for Ubuntu.

I have switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04 couple of days ago.

Thank You

Comment: "It works for windows but I cannot set the changes for Ubuntu" It is well because the setting folders aren't the same and Wine can not change the system configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about changing system configuration.
If your wine application can run in "batch mode" or automatically:

- set up an initial image e.g. 'calendar.png' as your wallpaper (that can contain anything, as long as it's a PNG file)
- set up a cron job to run your wine app and overwrite that file
- the desktop will be updated automatically

This assumes your wine app can produce PNG files (the recommended file formats for this type of images). Otherwise just replace any occurrence of PNG in this answer with the supported file format.

Cheers